# element click intercepted - cannot click on search button and grid column Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, grid-layout

This is the view:

[image]}

After running my code i got this error message:

```
element click intercepted: Element <button class="action-submit" type="button" data-bind="click: apply.bind($data, false)">...</button> is not clickable at point (393, 361). Other element would receive the click: <div data-role="spinner" data-component="product_listing.product_listing.product_columns" class="admin__data-grid-loading-mask">...</div>
xpath: //*[@id="container"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/button]
```

---

The SEARCH ICON has this:

```
<button class="action-submit" type="button" data-bind="click: apply.bind($data, false)">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Search'">Search</span>
    </button>
```

XPATH:

```
//*[@id="container"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/button
```

And then, i click on the grid and it has this:

```
<td data-bind="css: getFieldClass($row()), click: getFieldHandler($row()), template: getBody()">
<div class="data-grid-cell-content white-space-preserved" data-bind="html: $col.getLabel($row())">HISENSE 32"</div>
</td>
```

And XPATH:

```
//*[@id="container"]/div/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]
```

I did this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"container\"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/button")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"container\"]/div/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[7]")).click();
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First identify the element then use java `action` class to click on the element. Hope that will works for you.

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(10)); 
WebElement elementSearch = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[.//span[text()='Search']]")));
builder.moveToElement(elementSearch).click(elementSearch).build().perform();
WebElement elementItem = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//tr//td[4]")));
builder.moveToElement(elementItem).click(elementItem).build().perform();
```

Comment: Hey pal, i cannot do this: WebElement elementItem = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//td[contains(.,'HISENSE 32')]"))); because i will be filtering by different products. I need to click on the row. Do you get me?

Comment: @programming_amazing : can you try that. it should click on 1st row name element.

Comment: Could you please explain to me how did you amange to create that XPATH xpath("//tr//td[4]"). What's the logic behind?

Comment: It is the forth column of a row. 4 is index.

Comment: It has a strange behaviour. At first run it went good but at second i got this: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //button[.//span[text()='Search']] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: @programming_amazing : That was not the issue you have posted. I think it was clicking issue and I hope it is sorted now.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with JavaScript Executor:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"container\"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/button");

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Also, not sure but your xpath seems to broad; and when you click the Table maybe the DOM gets updated.

Check the xpath after clicking the table and see if it is still pointing to the button or not.